# Error while using React Context API: "TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm trying to make [state, setState] from "App.js" available to all child components by using context API. I have managed to do so just fine for most components but it's unexpectedly giving me back this error when trying to use it deeper down in the component tree:

```
"TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))"
```

I don't understand why context is accessible for some components but not to others since they're all wrapped by the Context.Provider.

This is how I'm creating the Context (I've simplified code snippets but left everything relevant to [state, setState] and Context):

### App.js

```js
export const Context = React.createContext();

function App() {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
  step: 0,
  })

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={[state, setState]}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div className="app">
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
              <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
            </Routes>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

After that I'm not using it directly in "Home" component, but I am using it in a Form component rendered by Home.jsx and it's working just fine. Form component renders children by a switch statement and its immediate children can access [state, setState] just fine by using useContext();

### Form.jsx

```html
import Step0 from "./Step0";
import Step1 from "./Step1";
import {useContext} from "react";
import { Context } from "../../App";

export default function Form () {

    const [state, setState] = useContext(Context);
    
    const nextStep = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setState({
            ...state,
            step: state.step + 1
        })
    }

    const prevStep = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // console.log(state);
        setState({
            ...state,
            step: state.step - 1
        })
    }

    switch(state.step) {
        case 1: 
            return (
                <Step0 nextStep={nextStep} />
        )
        case 2:
            return (
                <Step1 nextStep={nextStep} prevStep={prevStep}/>
            )
        default:
            return (
                <h1>default</h1>
            )
    }
}
```

useContext() is working without any problems in  and  components and [state, setState] are accessible.

However, I get the above mentioned error when  component is render from

### Step1.jsx

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Context } from "../../App";
import Results from "./Results";

export default function Step1() {
    
    const [state, setState] = useContext(Context);

    return (
       <ResultsEquals/>
       )
}
```

### Results.jsx

```js
import { useContext } from "react";
import Context from "../../App"; 

export default function Results() {

    const [state, setState] = useContext(Context);

    return (
    <h1>{state.step}</h1>
    )
}
```

Comment: why you insist that value of context be an array instead of object? like this 
<Context.Provider value={{state, setState}}>

Comment: I have tried changing it that way but instead of the mentioned error I get this one: 

"TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'state' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined."

but ONLY in the Results component. Context works OK both as array and as object for other components.

Comment: OMG I SOLVED IT. I just needed to import "Context" as {Context} with brackets and that solved it.

Comment: yes it does not export as default , you just import it as default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I just needed to import "Context" in consumer component as {Context} with brackets and that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

If you write "{Context}" using curly braces instead of "Context" where you are importing in Results.jsx file, the problem will be solved.